# Replace watermark text from searchbar html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like to change the placeholder and tooltip text on my search bar.

The search box looks like the image below. In other words, I would like to change  "Search ..." and "Search for:" to something else.

[image: Search bar]

Here is the relevant code from `searchform.php`:

```
 <div class="search-wrapper">

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

    <label>

        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'Tesseract' ) ?></span>             

        <input type="search" class="search-field placeholdit" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'Tesseract' ) ?>" />

    </label>

    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'Tesseract' ) ?>" />

</form>
```

I found out that replacing "Search for:" changes the tooltip text but how to change the placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try add `placeholder="New text"` to `input type="search"` element.

Additionally you could lookup whether you have some additional javascript that reacts with the element or its class (e.g. with class `placeholdit`).

Comment: I added `placeholder="New text"` and interesting thing happend - normally search bar looks like before but after clicking it "New test" appears. So It works when search box is clicked. When it is not there is still "Search..." text

Comment: Then it seems that you have some javascript that messes with it. Maybe with one of css class or with the type=search.
You could try to remove them or change the type to text just for test.

Comment: I deleted class parameter and `Search...` text disappeared. Everything works great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>"` with what you want.

You mean by "watermark" you mean the `Search ...` text?

Comment: Yes, `Search ...` text - the placeholder but when I used site inspector element was called  watermark. Replacing `value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>"` with `value="XXXXX"` didn't change anything. Is it possible that something overrides this formula ?